# Are my parameters sorted?

Tags: c++

I try to check are my parameters are sorted. I have code but it doesn't work... Could you tell me what should I fix? I think the problem is in first loop because result can be 0 in the end of list of parameters. I don't know how should I change it, I try to make that: when `atof(argv[i]) <= atof(argv[i + 1])` is not true, program should go to next for loop... It is my first C++ program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int result;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++) {
        if (atof(argv[i]) <= atof(argv[i + 1])) {
            result = 0;
        }
    }

    if (result == 0) {
        cout << "Sorted!" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }


    for (int i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++) {
        if (atof(argv[i]) >= atof(argv[i + 1])) {
            result = 2;
        }
    }

    if (result == 2) {
        cout << "Sorted!" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    else {
        cout << "Bad." << endl;
        system("pause");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "when `atof(argv[i]) <= atof(argv[i + 1])` is not true, program should go to next for loop" and it also go to next for loop when the condition is true.

Comment: Please tell us the desired behavior.

Comment: First assume that they are sorted.  So initialize your *result* variable.  Then all you have to do is check if they are *not* sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to initialize `result` by changing `int result;` to `int result = -1;`.

Replace `-1` with your desired initial value if you want.

Comment: Yep, stack variables in C++ are not initialized to a deterministic state. You get whatever was on the stack at the time of allocation. I hope the compiler generated a warning on that line!

Comment: Okay, I change every result to int result but when I choose my like parameters like: 5 5 5 5 1 program return "Bad.".

Comment: @Cleo You mean you changed the assignments to declaration and initialization of local variable, and stop updating the `result` that referenced by the `if` statements?

Answer (score 0):

Think about the first loop a little more. The logic you have says "if any number is less than the next number, set `result` to 0." So if you have a list like `5 3 4 2 1`, then when 3 and 4 are compared, `result` will be set to 0. And because the remaining numbers are decreasing, the value of `result` will not change for the remainder of the loop.

One solution you may want to consider is to assume the list is sorted, then if a number is encountered that is not in sorted order, set result to -1 and break out of the loop.